# TaskModuleResponseFactory.CreateResponse("") is not closing the TaskModule popup window

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, teams-toolkit, task-module

In Microsoft Teams Bot, I am trying to close a Task Module popup window after a action.submit button click by sending an empty response by using

```
protected override async Task<TaskModuleResponse> OnTeamsTaskModuleSubmitAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, TaskModuleRequest taskModuleRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
     var reply = MessageFactory.Text(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(taskModuleRequest));
     await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
     return TaskModuleResponseFactory.CreateResponse("");
}
```

However this code suddenly stopped working recently. Any other alternate option to close the task module window

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can close the task module using below code-

```
  private static async Task SendResponse(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, object body = null) 
    { await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(new Activity { Value = null, Type = ActivityTypesEx.InvokeResponse }); 
    }
```

In NodeJs-

```
 async handleTeamsTaskModuleSubmit(context, taskModuleRequest) {
  
        await context.sendActivity(MessageFactory.text('handleTeamsTaskModuleSubmit: ' + JSON.stringify(taskModuleRequest.data)));       
        return null;
    }
```

Reference Video-
https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-library-js/assets/93527375/dc62874e-b5ed-4330-97f5-e3dbf7e46639

Sample Link-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-task-module/csharp

Comment: In C# too, We can use return null;

Answer (score 0):

In C#, I could get it working using this code

```
protected override async Task<TaskModuleResponse> OnTeamsTaskModuleSubmitAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, TaskModuleRequest taskModuleRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var reply = MessageFactory.Text("OnTeamsTaskModuleSubmitAsync Value: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(taskModuleRequest));
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
        return null;
    }
```